# How to generate spectrogram image from Deeplearning4J's org.datavec.audio.Spectrogram?

Tags: java, spectrogram, deeplearning4j

I'm looking for the ways to generate a spectrogram image in an Android app.  I've found [this project](https://github.com/deeplearning4j/DataVec/blob/master/datavec-data/datavec-data-audio/src/main/java/org/datavec/audio/extension/Spectrogram.java) which appears to do half the work required: it loads the audio-file and creates a 2d array of intensities at a given time & frequency.  However, now I'm a bit lost: how does one generate a human-viewable picture from these data?

As far as I understand, it will involve mapping the intensity values from [-1,1] float range to pixel colors.  But being a noob in audio processing, I don't know how other applications do this.

I'm not looking for exact code: I'd appreciate just the description of a general approach.

Answer (score 0):

The library provides the function `public double[][] getNormalizedSpectrogramData()` to give back the audio spectrogram data, which is normalized numeric data ( inbetween 0 and ).

Return value first index is the number of samples, whereas the second index is the frequency range values ( I might not be right, corrections are welcome! ).

There are lots of ways to display this, I created a working example in JavaFX:

```
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.image.PixelWriter;
import javafx.scene.image.WritableImage;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import org.datavec.audio.Wave;
import org.datavec.audio.extension.*;

import java.io.InputStream;

public class Controller {
    public ImageView imgDisplay;

    public void loadMusic(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/sounds/oxp.wav");
        Wave wave = new Wave(is);
        Spectrogram sptr = new Spectrogram(wave);

        double[][] spData = sptr.getNormalizedSpectrogramData();
        WritableImage resImg = new WritableImage(spData.length,spData[0].length);
        PixelWriter pxWr = resImg.getPixelWriter();

        int x = 0, y = 0;
        for(double[] col : spData) /* or row?! */
        {
            y = 0;
            for(double item : col)
            {
                resImg.getPixelWriter().setColor(x,y, Color.rgb((int)(item * 255),(int)(item * 255),(int)(item * 255)));
                y++;
            }
            x++;
        }

        System.out.println("Done! Image size is: " + x + "," + y);
        imgDisplay.setFitWidth(x);
        imgDisplay.setFitHeight(y);
        imgDisplay.setImage(resImg);
    }
}
```